# rEFind remove boot entries

Tags: refind

I want to delete some boot-entries from rEFind, and apply my theme correctly.

I have a Mac with OS X, KDE Neon, Windows and Manjaro installed. I want 1 entry for OS X (currently 3), 1 for KDE Neon, 1 for Windows and 1 for Manjaro.

Currently I have:

1. Boot Mac OS X from Recovery HD
2. Boot EFI\refit\refit.efi from Macintosh HD
3. Boot Mac OS X from Macintosh HD (KEEP!)
4. Boot Fallback boot loader from EFI
5. Boot boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic from KDE (KEEP!)
6. Boot boot/vmlinuz-4.9-x86_64 from manjaro (KEEP!)
7. Boot Linux (legacy) from whole disk volume
8. Boot Windows (Legacy) from Windows (KEEP!)

So, I am **think** #7 is from me installing grub to dev/sda (whole disc) during the latest manjaro install. I don't use grub - any way to remove it?

How do I get rid of the 2 extra Mac OS X entries? I really don't need them, since I can boot into the OS X recovery partition by using the OS X bootloader instead.

I have no idea what #4 is...

I also have a theme installed, in dev/sda1 -> EFI/refind/themes and have it applied. Though icons are not set to the correct entries. Any easy way I can solve this?

Here is my partition table:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     409640 273847135 273437496 130.4G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sda3  669812736 977104895 307292160 146.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  273848320 275118079   1269760   620M Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sda5  412526592 647391231 234864640   112G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  275118080 412526591 137408512  65.5G Linux filesystem
```

sda5 is KDE, sda6 is manjaro. sda4 is Recovery HD for OS X.